# GUI testing by click x,y

Tags: user-interface, testing, xpath, automated-tests

I want to ask for help to deal with GUI testing of Web Application.

I'm looking for software where I can write script which will do this:

- Click (x,y)
- Write data (like login, password)
- Check radio and checkboxes
- Validate output data

And it'd be very big + if it can change between windows.

I was trying to testing GUI by:

- Selenium
- JAutomation
- Sahi

However I couldn't test it by xpath because application:

- doesn't have unique id
- classes are changing every reloading
- absolute xpath depends on sequence of steps performed

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sahi, you do not need to use xpaths. Also, you must not click on coordinates to click on a button. I would say give Sahi Pro a try and it should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some test in similar situation with Sahi.

If you have a text near to your target, you can use the _parentX, _in, _above, etc functions to catch it. For example:

```
_click(_button("buttonText", _in(_parentRow(_cell("someText")))));
```

If it isn't possible you can try an image based tool like Sikuli or Autoit.

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)

[AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) and
 [ImageSearch](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/)

The Sikuli has a fancy IDE and some ugly bugs. The Autoit is faster and more robust but the language itself is not to cool.

With theese tools you can send keystrokes and mouse clicks to specified coordinates and find elements by images.

The method has some drawback. If your site style (css) or your desktop style changed you have to update all images in the tests.

Good luck!